# Why FB sends code param when it sends signed_request too after user athorization?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

This is regarding Facebook apps. After the user clicks on Allow button on the authorization page (OAuth page) then the user is redirected to the app with a `code` param in the query string. According to [FB doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) we should use the value of this param to get the access code needed for FB API calls.

I use FB's PHP-SDK. After the user is redirected from OAuth page then I call `$facebook->getUserAccessToke()` to get the access token. This code seems to fetch the access token directly from the `signed_rquest` (present in the cookie). It never needs to use `code` param. I don't understand why `code` param is sent then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on your app settings, currently its working without the code, but you will have to migrate to the now standard oauth2.0 process.

see https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php for how to login users.

in short words, you dont have to take care of the token or code parameter, the SDK handles it itself. (via $_REQUEST array)

Comment: I use OAuth 2.0. This is a new App, so no deprecated API is used.

Comment: Regarding this example. I don't understand this 'show login button' thing. All I want is that when the user tries to access my app then he will be redirected to OAuth page. This should take care of all things like logging-in the user and authorizing the app.

Comment: you dont need to show login button, just redirect the user to the url you get from `$facebook->getLoginUrl();`. if user has not given you permission he is presentet with the permission screen, if user already have given permission he is immidatly redirected back to your side.

Comment: Oh. I was manually creating my own url as per FB's doc and redirecting the user there.